# Solve for the inverse of $\mathbf I - \tan(\frac{\phi}{2}) \mathbf {\hat \omega}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-groups, inverse, rotations

Original problem comes from [some notes on rotations](http://robotics.caltech.edu/~jwb/courses/ME115/handouts/rotation.pdf) (at the last page), which was devoted to deriving [Rodrigues' rotation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula). The complete problem is to show why
$$(\mathbf I - \tan(\frac{\phi}{2}) \mathbf {\hat \omega})^{-1}(\mathbf I + \tan(\frac{\phi}{2}) \mathbf {\hat \omega}) = \mathbf I + \sin \phi \mathbf {\hat \omega} +(1 - \cos \phi)\mathbf {\hat \omega}^2.$$
Here, $\mathbf {\hat \omega}$ is a skew-symmetric matrix:
$$\mathbf {\hat \omega} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & - \omega_3 & \omega_2 \\ \omega_3 & 0 & -\omega_1 \\ -\omega_2 & \omega_1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
I think the key is to solve for the inverse of $\mathbf I - \tan(\frac{\phi}{2}) \mathbf {\hat \omega}$, can anyone help out?

Comment: Why do not the inverse to shift onto the right side and to make some trigonometric transformations ? Maybe these formulas can help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Half-angle_formulae

Comment: Additionally we also have $\hat{\omega}^3=-\hat{\omega} $

Comment: @Widawensen Thanks for your enlightening implications. I have finished the proof on my scratch paper! :)

Comment: I'm glad to be helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

It boils down to show:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
(\mathbf I + \tan(\frac{\phi}{2}) \mathbf {\hat \omega}) &=(\mathbf I - \tan(\frac{\phi}{2}) \mathbf {\hat \omega})( \mathbf I + \sin \phi \mathbf {\hat \omega} +(1 - \cos \phi)\mathbf {\hat \omega}^2) \\
&=\mathbf I + \sin \phi{\hat \omega} + (1-\cos \phi){\hat \omega}^{2}-\tan \frac{\phi}{2} {\hat \omega} - \sin \phi \tan \frac{\phi}{2}{\hat \omega}^2+\tan \frac{\phi}{2} (1-\cos\phi){\hat \omega} \\
&= \mathbf I + (\sin \phi-\tan \frac{\phi}{2}\cos \phi){\hat \omega}+(1-\cos\phi-\tan \frac{\phi}{2}\sin \phi){\hat \omega}^2.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Now let $t=\tan \frac{\phi}{2}$, and $\cos \phi=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2},\sin \phi=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$. So above expression is equal to
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& \mathbf I + (\frac{2t}{1+t^2}-\frac{t-t^3}{1+t^2}){\hat \omega}+
(1-\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}-\frac{2t^2}{1+t^2}){\hat \omega}^2 \\
=& \mathbf I + t\hat \omega
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}